# I try to get results from table with multiple where and/or clauses Query Builder

Tags: sql, laravel, where-clause

i try to get results from table with multiple where and/or clauses.

My SQL statement is:

```
select *
  from ceri.movimentacao_parcela_repasse mpr
  inner join ceri.movimentacao_parcela mp on (mp.id_movimentacao_parcela = mpr.id_movimentacao_parcela)
  inner join ceri.pedido p on (p.id_pedido = mp.id_pedido)
  inner join ceri.produto pd on (pd.id_produto = p.id_produto)
  where mpr.id_repasse = 4
    and mpr.in_repasse_aberto = 'S'
    and ( (pd.id_grupo_produto = 1 and p.id_situacao_pedido_grupo_produto = 7 ) or (pd.id_grupo_produto = 2
    and p.id_situacao_pedido_grupo_produto = 17) )
```

My Code in Laravel is:

**first** attempt

```
->where('movimentacao_parcela_repasse.id_repasse', '=', DB::raw('4'))
->where('movimentacao_parcela_repasse.in_repasse_aberto', '=', DB::raw('\'S\''))
->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('produto.id_grupo_produto',DB::raw('1')) //-- 1 Pesquisa
          ->where('produto.id_situacao_pedido_grupo_produto',DB::raw('7')); // 7 -- Finalizado
})
->orWhere(function($query) {
    $query->where('produto.id_grupo_produto',DB::raw('2')) //2 Certidão /
          ->where('produto.id_situacao_pedido_grupo_produto',DB::raw('17')); //17 -- Finalizado
});

// RESULT

and ("produto"."id_grupo_produto" = 1 and "pedido"."id_situacao_pedido_grupo_produto" = 7) or ("produto"."id_grupo_produto" = 2 and "pedido"."id_situacao_pedido_grupo_produto" = 17)
```

**second** attempt

```
->where('movimentacao_parcela_repasse.id_repasse', '=', DB::raw('4'))
->where('movimentacao_parcela_repasse.in_repasse_aberto', '=', DB::raw('\'S\''))
->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('produto.id_grupo_produto',DB::raw('1')) 
    ->where('pedido.id_situacao_pedido_grupo_produto',DB::raw('7'))
    ->orWhere(function($query) {
        $query->where('produto.id_grupo_produto',DB::raw('2')) 
        ->where('pedido.id_situacao_pedido_grupo_produto',DB::raw('17')); 
    });
});

// RESULT

and ("produto"."id_grupo_produto" = 1 and "pedido"."id_situacao_pedido_grupo_produto" = 7 or ("produto"."id_grupo_produto" = 2 and "pedido"."id_situacao_pedido_grupo_produto" = 17))
```

**I do not want the way i wanted**

```
and ( (pd.id_grupo_produto = 1 and p.id_situacao_pedido_grupo_produto = 7 ) or (pd.id_grupo_produto = 2 and p.id_situacao_pedido_grupo_produto = 17)  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
->where('movimentacao_parcela_repasse.id_repasse', '=', DB::raw('4'))
->where('movimentacao_parcela_repasse.in_repasse_aberto', '=', DB::raw('\'S\''))
->where(function($query) {
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('produto.id_grupo_produto',DB::raw('1')) 
        ->where('pedido.id_situacao_pedido_grupo_produto',DB::raw('7'))
    })
    ->orWhere(function($query) {
        $query->where('produto.id_grupo_produto',DB::raw('2')) 
        ->where('pedido.id_situacao_pedido_grupo_produto',DB::raw('17')); 
    });
});
```